# Will my dead iphone still erase if it were to ever get revived even if it were removed from my icloud?

Tags: iphone, icloud, security

Long story short, iphone 7 died suddenly, apple store confirmed it dead, i suspect logic board problem but in the end i don't know, now my question:

I am thinking of selling the dead iphone as a parts phone, and since it died suddenly i was never able to properly unlink my icloud and factory reset it. 
If i sent an erase request from icloud and then remove the device from my icloud through "Find My Iphone"(with the erase still pending), will the erase request still go through in the case someone was able to fix it? Or should i not remove it from my icloud at all?

the phone is passcoded with a very strong password so i know the data will still be protected by encryption to an extent but i am thinking worst case scenario.